# Using generated C/C++ Code from Simulink in own C++ project

Tags: c++, c, matlab, code-generation, simulink

I'm searching for a good tutorial or explanation for the following procedure.
I want to generate C/C++ Code from Simulink (Simulink Coder/Embedded Coder) and interface it with own C/C++ Code, such that I can use my existing algorithms from Simulink. I want to use sensor decoders explicitly in C/C++.

I know that I could use S-functions to integrate my decoders in Simulink, but I want to do the exact opposite because of several reasons.

Is there anyone who can provide me good tutorials/informations about that? Is there a standard C/C++ file structure to interface code-generated Simulink models?

Best regards
Max

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard interfacing setup (just a default), that is why you can configure the interface of the generated code. These days the tool itself includes a helpful wizard to help you defining the interface of the generated code, see https://nl.mathworks.com/products/embedded-coder/features.html#configuring-for-code-generation

In case you are looking for C++ class generation (instead of a function-based interface), take a look at the following link:
https://nl.mathworks.com/help/ecoder/ug/customize-generated-cpp-class-interfaces.html